# how to use queries on 2 relationships in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, multidimensional-array, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have model with 2 relationships. I want to add where condition on each relationship.

For example show me a room that date is `4/11/2019` and the city in `london`

**Controller:**

```
    $test = Property::with('dates','details')->get();
```

**$test result:**

It may be a bit long but I expanded whole result so you can check the relations as dates is in a pivot relation :

```
Collection {#1708 ▼


 #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => Property {#1457 ▼
      #guarded: []
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "properties"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:8 [▶]
      #original: array:8 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:2 [▼
        "dates" => Collection {#1607 ▼
          #items: array:1 [▼
            0 => Date {#1600 ▼
              #connection: "mysql"
              #table: "dates"
              #primaryKey: "id"
              #keyType: "int"
              +incrementing: true
              #with: []
              #withCount: []
              #perPage: 15
              +exists: true
              +wasRecentlyCreated: false
              #attributes: array:7 [▶]
              #original: array:9 [▶]
              #changes: []
              #casts: []
              #dates: []
              #dateFormat: null
              #appends: []
              #dispatchesEvents: []
              #observables: []
              #relations: array:1 [▼
                "pivot" => Pivot {#1602 ▼
                  +incrementing: false
                  #guarded: []
                  #connection: null
                  #table: "date_property"
                  #primaryKey: "id"
                  #keyType: "int"
                  #with: []
                  #withCount: []
                  #perPage: 15
                  +exists: true
                  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
                  #attributes: array:2 [▶]
                  #original: array:2 [▶]
                  #changes: []
                  #casts: []
                  #dates: []
                  #dateFormat: null
                  #appends: []
                  #dispatchesEvents: []
                  #observables: []
                  #relations: []
                  #touches: []
                  +timestamps: false
                  #hidden: []
                  #visible: []
                  #fillable: []
                  +pivotParent: Property {#1461 ▶}
                  #foreignKey: "property_id"
                  #relatedKey: "date_id"
                }
              ]
              #touches: []
              +timestamps: true
              #hidden: []
              #visible: []
              #fillable: []
              #guarded: array:1 [▶]
            }
          ]
        }
        "details" => PropertyDetail {#1702 ▼
          #fillable: array:7 [▶]
          #connection: "mysql"
          #table: "property_details"
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #keyType: "int"
          +incrementing: true
          #with: []
          #withCount: []
          #perPage: 15
          +exists: true
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
          #attributes: array:10 [▶]
          #original: array:10 [▼
            "id" => 52
            "property_id" => 65
            "state" => "london"
            "city" => "london"
            "address" => "5"
            "post_code" => 5
            "placearea" => 1
            "telephone" => 5
            "created_at" => "2019-04-09 21:03:10"
            "updated_at" => "2019-04-09 21:03:10"
          ]
          #changes: []
          #casts: []
          #dates: []
          #dateFormat: null
          #appends: []
          #dispatchesEvents: []
          #observables: []
          #relations: []
          #touches: []
          +timestamps: true
          #hidden: []
          #visible: []
          #guarded: array:1 [▶]
        }
      ]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
    }
    1 => Property {#1458 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please close the `#relations` and expand the `#attributes` for the `dates` Collection. Then repost your dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter the entities by conditions on their relations, then you need `whereHas()` (see [Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)):

```
$searchDate = '2019-04-11';
$searchCity = 'london';

$test = Property::with('dates','details')
        ->whereHas('dates', function($query) use($searchDate) {
            $query->where('date', $searchDate);
        })
        ->whereHas('details', function($query) use($searchCity) {
            $query->where('city', $searchCity);
        })
        ->get();
```

If you also want to filter the returned relations by the same condition, then you can do it within `with()` (see [Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)):

```
$test = Property::with(['details', 'dates' => function($query) use($searchDate) {
            $query->where('date', $searchDate);
        }])
        ->whereHas('dates', function($query) use($searchDate) {
            $query->where('date', $searchDate);
        })
        ->whereHas('details', function($query) use($searchCity) {
            $query->where('city', $searchCity);
        })
        ->get();
```

You only need to do that for `dates`, since there can be only one `details` relation, which is already constrained to `'london'`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this,

```
$data = Property::with(['dates' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('datefield', 'like', '4/11/2019'); // datefield I ain't saw in your output, you can replace it 
}],['details' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('city', 'like', 'london');
}])->get();
dd($data);
```

Refer documentation how to use it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships).

I hope your date format in the table is as `m/d/Y` if not you have to follow below steps.

```
$date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime(str_replace("/","-",$yourdate)));
```

You can use `$date` variable in place of `4/11/2019`.

> Note: Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking
>   at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and
>   the separator is a dash (-, the date string is parsed as y-m-d.

**EDIT**

```
$property = Property::with(['dates' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('datefield', 'like', '4/11/2019');
}])->get();
```

Comment: well rahull i tried that but yet no luck with it it return all the properties to me and the filters are not working some how

Comment: no i am just returning all my properties with the relation of date but not detail relationship

Comment: You mean, dates condition worked and details is still not worked right means 4/11/2019 this condition worked but london condition wont worked right?

Comment: nope conditions not working at all its a bit wierd but it return all properties and conditions not working

Comment: Once check my edit portion, you must change `datefield` with your column name in your mysql table. You must check value of date in your table in format `m/d/Y`. If both these criteria are fine. It must work at any cost as per laravel documentation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191706/discussion-between-farshad-and-rahul-meshram).

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try

```
$property = Property::with(['dates' => function ($query) {
    $query->whereDate('datefield', '4/11/2019');
}])->get();
```

and you do not need `LIKE`. See [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses), I am not saying `LIKE` will not work, but using a `=` or `whereDate` will be more accurate.

Can you try

```
$data = Property::with(['dates' => function ($query) {
            $query->whereDate('your_date_field', '=', '4/11/2019');
        }],['details' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('city', 'london');
        }])->get();
```

or

```
$data = Property::whereHas('dates', function($query){
    $query->where('your_date_field', '4/11/2019');
})->whereHas('city', function($query){
    $query->where('city', 'london');
})->get();
```

Comment: nope again it returns all the properties to me and dont apply the where filters but when i change city or date to some thing else i get the error that this colomn cant be find

Comment: @Farshad Can you tell me your exact date field name and edit your question with some demo data with expected result?

Comment: date fields is exacly 'date' and city name is london and the problem is not that i dont get the result the problem is that i get the result :) for example if i dont have the london city in my database i should get nothing but i get all the properties every time

Comment: So, you want your conditions to be applied always and not make it optional?

Comment: sorry if iam not clear i want it to be optional but i am hard coding it for now to see if it is working or not and the where is not working i dont know why :(

Comment: @Farshad if city lodon is present you want the result related to london and if records related to london is not there you want to display empty result, but you are getting all records in stead of empty result, am I correct?

Comment: @Farshad Also can you specify the models and the relationships in your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191892/discussion-between-prafulla-kumar-sahu-and-farshad).

Comment: @Farshad Can you edit your question to specify the models and the relationships?

Answer (score 0):

***Most important thing is Date field and City should be use equal condition not `like` condition.***

**Notes :** You should check your date format for proper data output.

```
$data = Property::with(['dates' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('your_date_field', '=', '4/11/2019');
        }],['details' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('city', '=', 'london');
        }])->get();
```

You can also use `whereDate()` function to compare date field.

```
$data = Property::with(['dates' => function ($query) {
                $query->whereDate('your_date_field', '4/11/2019');
            }],['details' => function ($query) {
                $query->where('city', '=', 'london');
            }])->get();
```

Comment: nope again it returns all the properties to me and dont apply the where filters but when i change city or date to some thing else i get the error that this colomn cant be find

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
$data = Property::with([
    'dates' => function ($query) {
        $query->whereDate('your_date_field', 'formatted_date');
    },
    'details' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('city', '=', 'london');
    }
])->get();
```

If you need details of property only, not the relation data, then you can try for :

```
whereHas
```